# ViewPager and preserving faded button in same state in next page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am creating a slideshow where I show some buttons. When the user taps on the screen, the buttons fade away. I use a state variable to figure out what state the buttons should be in. However, it seems like the next page gets created and cached. Hence, when I fade the buttons and move to the next page, the buttons are visible, but in the following pages they are not (as the rendering is happening post my setting the state). See my code below from class the extends PagerAdapter.

```
    final Animation topSlideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.top_slide_in);
    final Animation topSlideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.top_slide_out);

    if (isMetaVisible) {
        btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        btnDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    topSlideOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            btnDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
    });
    topSlideIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }
    });

    imgDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isMetaVisible) {
                isMetaVisible = false;
                btnDelete.startAnimation(topSlideOut);
                btnClose.startAnimation(topSlideOut);
            } else {
                isMetaVisible = true;
                btnDelete.startAnimation(topSlideIn);
                btnClose.startAnimation(topSlideIn);
            }
        }
    });
```

On a related note, since the buttons are per page, when I swipe the buttons move as well. Is there a simpler way to do this where the buttons are outside of the ViewPager and static even when I swipe?

Comment: Sry I dont have any code since not at the office, but you can override on position change in the pager adapter or detect when the fragment is shown to the user

Comment: @JohanV Not exactly sure what method you mean by "on position change". I can't seem to find anything like that. The current code executes inside `instantiateItem`

Comment: once i get back at the office i look more into this